# Going back and forth between algebra $A$ and regular module ${}_AA$ in GAP

Tags: modules, gap, algebras

Let `A` be an algebra over some field (e.g., `Rationals`) and `L := LeftIdeal(A, [g]);` be a left ideal generated by some element `g`. It seems that it is impossoble to consider the quotinet module `A/L` of `A`. Hence, I consider the left regular module of `A`, i.e., `A` considered as a left module over itself. GAP provides `F:=AdjointModule(A)`. For some `g in F` I issue `I:=SubAlgebraModule(A, [g]);` and pass to the quotient `pi:=NaturalHomomorphismBySubAlgebraModule(F,L); Q:=Range(pi);`. Now, assume `q in Q`. I can find a `m:=PreImagesRepresentative(pi, q);` of `q` in `F`. But actually, this is an element of `A`, which GAP sees different:

```
> m in F;
true
> m in A;
false
```

so how can I take an element of the left regular module `F` and obtain the corresponding element of `A`?

Comment: Find corresponding bases, decompose in one basis and form the linear combination of the other base with the same coefficients.

Comment: @ahulpke But how can I ensure that the bases obtained using `Basis(A)` and `Basis(F)` are related in any way?